# SQL Match two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got the following Situation and maybe the is a more comfortable way for my Problem.

I got two tables (for Example ORDERS, CANCEL), each table got values and there is no way to join them.

Here are some records to understand what i want to do.

**ORDERS:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**CANCEL:**

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Now i need the following Output:

```
1  A
1  B
1  C
1  D
1  E
2  A
2  B
2  C
2  D
2  E
3  A
```

And so on. And maybe i need to match a thirth table. Anyone a Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select o.col1, c.col1
from orders o cross join
     cancels c;
```